# Leaflet marker filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have leaflet map that shows 30-50 different markers.
Below the map I have a simple HTML form which should be used for filtering.

Users would choose filters (for example: "City" and "id"). Then map should show only markers that satisfy those two filters. All other markers should be removed.

I guess that logic to do so is this:

After filter is set, search json source of markers and remove all that are not requested. But I have no idea how to implement it. Also how to restore all default markers after filter is dismissed? Also filter should be outside of leaflet map as separate HTML form.

And this is how I initialize markers

```js
var city = [
  {name: "City1", loc: [11.111, 22.222], id: "1"},
  {name: "City2", loc: [12.111, 23.222], id: "2"}, 
  {name: "City3", loc: [13.111, 24.222], id: "3"}, 
  {name: "City3", loc: [14.111, 25.222], id: "4"}
];
```

I didn't include rest of code as it is standard leaflet code so to keep it compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the initial array of cities using an `ID` and `name`:

```js
const cities = [
  {name: "City1", loc: [11.111, 22.222], id: "1"},  
  {name: "City2", loc: [12.111, 23.222], id: "2"}, 
  {name: "City3", loc: [13.111, 24.222], id: "3"}, 
  {name: "City3", loc: [14.111, 25.222], id: "4"}
];

let selectedCity = "City2";
let selectedId = "2";

let filteredList = cities.filter( city => {
  return city.name === selectedCity && city.id === selectedId
});

console.log( filteredList );
```